# What is the most efficient way to find if any two numbers in a given sorted array add up to any third one in the array?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is an interview question I saw somewhere and came up with this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
class SumTwo
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Random r=new Random();

        int arr[]=new int[5];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=r.nextInt(20);
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        printArr(arr);
        System.out.println(checkSum(arr));

    }

    public static boolean checkSum(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i=2;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(check(arr,0,i-1,arr[i]))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static boolean check(int[] arr, int st, int en, int sum)
    {

        int add=0;
        while(st<en)
        {
            add=arr[st]+arr[en];
            if(add==sum)
                return true;
            else if(add>sum)
                en--;
            else
                st++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void printArr(int[] arr)
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @NPE if I can do better than this

Comment: doesn't look so bad, didnt try it out but looks correct and you are taking advantage of the sorted array and the fact that you are looking for a sum of two other values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yours is O(n^3). (EDIT: I misread it, you are correct, yours is O(n^2)) Like Louis Wasserman said, there's a simple algorithm for O(n^2 log n), and here's one for O(n^2) using a bit of extra memory:

```
public static boolean checkSum(int[] arr) {
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int n : arr) {
        set.add(n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (set.contains(arr[i] + arr[j])) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Might need a special case for arrays containing zeros, depending on the problem definition, but the idea is there.

Intuitively, it seems there might be a clever way of doing this that's O(n log n) or so, but I can't immediately find any. I'll keep thinking on it a bit more, this is a good question.

Comment: HashSet does not necessarily give you O(1) lookup so this is not a O(n^2). If you use an array preallocated to the maximum integer then you have a proper worst case O(1) lookup :)

Comment: Note that `[2,0]` will yield true, which contradicts the requirements of third (I assume different) number

Comment: amit- correct, thus my note about probably needing a special case for zeros.